# Can't retrieve symbols from KDB using QPython

Tags: pandas, dataframe, kdb, qpython

I am trying to pull a KDB table into a python dataframe. The table is created successfully, all float columns are visable but symbol columns are blank.

I am using:

```
with qconnection.QConnection(host = 'XXXX', port = 5001, pandas = True) as q:
   df = q.sync('table')
```

Meta on this table shows the string columns are of type 's'. type of table is 98h.
I am using python 3.7.

Anyone has encountered this before?

Comment: The symbols should get unenumerated automatically when you query over IPC but perhaps that isn't happening? Can you try stringing the symbol columns within the select, just to see if you can get the symbols in string form: `df = q.sync('update string symcol1, string symcol2 from table')`. If you can see the strings using this method then it points to something up with the de-enumeration of the symbols

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! It does not work with string either. Also tried stringing the timestamps that were appearing before and that made them disappear.

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure qpython is compatible with python 3.7? I'm not too familiar with qpython (I use pyq) so I'm not sure if you need to do something special with symbols/strings

Comment: I can try using it on 3.6. Let me try with pyq, never worked with it before. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Terry that this might be an issue with using python 3.7 with qpython. The project has been in maintenance mode for a while now with lots of issues noted on their github page https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython

can you please try this and see what is returned? it looks to be working fine on python 3.6

```
#open a q session with 'q -p 5000' on localhost
from qpython import qconnection
import pandas as pd
import sys

q = qconnection.QConnection(host = 'localhost', port = 5000, pandas = True)
q.open()
df = q.sendSync('flip `nums`syms`strings!(1 2;`hello`world;("hello";"world"))')
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
print(df.meta)
print(sys.version)

#the return using python 3.6, kdb 4.0 and qpython from anaconda
   nums      syms   strings
0     1  b'hello'  b'hello'
1     2  b'world'  b'world'
nums        int64
syms       object
strings    object
dtype: object
metadata(qtype=98, nums=7, syms=11, strings=0)
3.6.12 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep  8 2020, 23:10:56) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Giving that a try today, I'll let you know if it works.